# How to get nginx to return 404 unless a specific domain name is requested?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have a nginx server and I'd like to return 404 when `anything.mydomain.com` is requested except when `anything` is `www`, `mypythonapp1` or `mypythonapp2`

I created a `00-noredirect` file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name _;

    return 404;
}
```

Unfortunately, everything gets redirect to `mypythonapp1`.

The other server blocks are as follow:

```
server {
    listen mypythonapp1.mydomain.com:80;
    server_name mypythonapp1.mydomain.com;
    (...) 
    listen mypythonapp1.mydomain.com:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    (...)
}
```

I think this might be related to `certbot` additions in my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mypythonapp1`, even though I'm not sure:

```
(...)
    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
(...)
```

Is there something I have to add to `00-noredirect` to avoid this unwanted behaviour?

EDIT: as requested by @Tim, here's my -almost complete- nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mypythonapp1.mydomain.com;

    disable_symlinks off;

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/mypythonapp/mypythonapp/mypythonapp/static;
    }

    location / { try_files $uri @yourapplication; }
    location @yourapplication {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/app/mypythonapp1/socket;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    # some ssl magic here
    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



}
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mypythonapp2.mydomain.com;

    disable_symlinks off;

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/mypythonapp/mypythonapp/mypythonapp/static;
    }

    location / { try_files $uri @yourapplication; }
    location @yourapplication {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/app/mypythonapp2/socket;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    # some ssl magic here
    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.mydomain.com mydomain.com;
    root /home/me/mystaticwebsite/;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    # some ssl magic here
    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$uri;
    } # managed by Certbot




}
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    return 444;
}

# this last bit I commented out because it broke everything...

#server {
#    listen 443 default_server;
#
#    server_name _;
#
#    return 444;
#}
```

EDIT2: Examining `error.log` (why didn't I do that before...) I realized that the last part "broke everything" because `no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking`. I ended up copying the `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` lines that `certbot` added to the other domains. Now I still have a certificate warning when requesting `anything.mydomain.com` but at least if I bypass it, I don't access `mypythonapp1` which is all that I really wanted in the first place.

Comment: The new `server` block only matches if the other server blocks do not. So the solution depends on what is in your other `server` blocks. You can use `nginx -T` to display the full `nginx` configuration.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect the content of my other server blocks. `nginx -T` doesn't work with my nginx version.

Comment: Test the configuration using `nginx -t`.

Comment: `# nginx -t`
`nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok`
`nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

Comment: Try `listen 80 default_server;` in the new `server` block.

Comment: It didn't change anything. FWIW, I'm always redirected to HTTPS, no matter what.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#mixed_name_ip_based_servers remove address from `listen` directives

Comment: @AlexeyTen I replaced all relevant lines by `listen 80;` and `listen 443;`, now nothing works (ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED) unless I remove `00-noredirect`, in which case *.mydomain.com (except www or mypythonapp2) return mypythonapp1. I'm reading the docs again and again and can't figure out how to do this. It sounds so basic: I just don't want nginx to return anything when the wrong domain name is requested :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create server blocks that specify the server_name by domain names you want to service. Next create a default server to handle all others. You shouldn't return 404, return a more appropriate code.

```
server {
  # These can be in individual servers if you like
  server_name anything.mydomain.com www.mydomain.com etc.mydomain.com

  # add configuration
}


# This just prevents Nginx picking a random default server if it doesn't know which
# server block to send a request to
server {
  listen      80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  return      444; # "Connection closed without response"
}
```

Comment: Nice! But I couldn't avoid http**s**://anything.mydomain.com to point to `mypythonapp1`, resulting in a invalid certificate warning.
I tried adding listen `listen 443 default_server;` but this just broke everything...

Comment: For https you need your certificate to explicitly include each domain and subdomain, or use wildcards for subdomains, otherwise you'll get a certificate warning. There's no way around that.

Comment: My problem isn't with the warning itself but with the fact that mypythonapp1 is returned for *.mydomain.com. I'd like nginx to return 444, or redirect if someone enters https://anything.mydomain.com

Comment: Please edit your question to show every server block in your Nginx configuration. You can trim out locations, SSL configuration, etc, really just want to see server_name and listen directives _exactly_ as your config has them. I've never used listen servername:port, I always have server_name and listen port separate.

Comment: I actually removed `servername` from the `listen` directives, because of the conversation in the comments. I added a link to my full config file, it looked a bit too long to paste here.

Comment: I inlined your config file, length is fine. It's best if your question stands alone, without requiring someone to read comments to understand it. The next step is you need to demonstrate the problem. curl a working url, and show correlated error / access logs. Then curl the one that should return 444, and again show correlated error and access logs. Restart nginx before the demo. Looks ok, not sure why it's returning the python website instead of 444, should be pretty easily solvable though.

Comment: Examining the logs, good advice (doh !). So the problem was that nginx needs a `ssl_certificate` and a `ssl_certificate_key` for each `listen 443`. I edited my question, that now has its own answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
 if ($host !~ ^(www.mydomain.com|mypythonapp1.mydomain.com|mypythonapp2.mydomain.com|mydomain.com|localhost)$ ) { return 404; }
```

if you need to return 404 when user requested any domain that does not match to your list, you have to simply add this line to your server block

Comment: This seems like a hack, whereas Tim has already offered a real solution.

Comment: Although if statements are considered evil, in this case it has the extra benefit of not needing to setup SSL certificates when trying to block unknown hosts on HTTPS